# How to fix "TypeError: must be real number, not str" error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pysal

I keep on getting this error. My data is formatted correctly, but I just can't get it to create a KDTree.

I have one data set, let's call it A, and another data set, let's call it B. Both sets have many latitude and longitude coordinates. I want to see how many of B's points lie in a certain radius of each of A's points.

All help is welcome!

CODE:

```
from pysal.cg.kdtree import KDTree
from pysal.cg import RADIUS_EARTH_MILES

trees_xys = results_df[['latitude', 'longitude']].values
trees_tree = KDTree(trees_xys, distance_metric='Arc', radius=RADIUS_EARTH_MILES)
```

ERROR:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-a46d6648d543> in <module>
      3 
      4 trees_xys = results_df[['latitude', 'longitude']].values
----> 5 trees_tree = KDTree(trees_xys, distance_metric='Arc', radius=RADIUS_EARTH_MILES)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysal\cg\kdtree.py in KDTree(data, leafsize, distance_metric, radius)
     54             return scipy.spatial.cKDTree(data, leafsize)
     55     elif distance_metric == 'Arc':
---> 56         return Arc_KDTree(data, leafsize, radius)
     57 
     58 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysal\cg\kdtree.py in __init__(self, data, leafsize, radius)
     88         self.radius = radius
     89         self.circumference = 2 * math.pi * radius
---> 90         temp_KDTree.__init__(self, list(map(sphere.toXYZ, data)), leafsize)
     91 
     92     def _toXYZ(self, x):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysal\cg\sphere.py in toXYZ(pt)
    110     x, y, z
    111     """
--> 112     phi, theta = list(map(math.radians, pt))
    113     phi, theta = phi + pi, theta + (pi / 2)
    114     x = 1 * sin(theta) * cos(phi)

TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

Comment: What's your data type for `trees_xys`, I think 'latitude' or 'longitude' series contains object dtype. please convert into numeric. try this, `results_df[['latitude', 'longitude']].astype(float).values`

Comment: trees_xys is a numpy array

Comment: have you tried what I suggested ?